# How get only firebase document that have specific sub document id or is there alternative way?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get a document that contain specific sub document id for calculating max and min data without querying whole collection.

The document structure is similar to this.

```
Collection: Student
    /* unrelated field */
    The document
    Subcollection: Grade
      Document: Math
        Subcollection: Score
          Document: Johny
```

The query would get all the data which subdocument's id is Johny so I can calculate min and max score that Johny grade to normalize the score.

If there is an alternative data structure choice that can accomplish this, feel free to recommend as an answer. I can still migrate all data as most of documents has no subcollection.

Comment: The presented structure is unclear. For example This is a collection of students, assuming the documentId is perhaps a student id or a id generated by Firebase, why is the students name buried 4 levels deep? Why is the subcollection called Grade? Is there any reason you don't store the students and their personal information in one collection and then the students classes and grades in another? What does *max and min data* mean in this use case. Maximum... grade? Number of classes? Grade for all classes or just Math classes? Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

On your current structure, you could query it like this:

```
var JohnyScore = []
db.collection("Student").get().then(function(doc) {
    doc.collection("Grade").get().then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(doc2) {
            doc2.collection("Score").where("id", "==", "Johny").get().then(function(snapshot2) {
                JohnyScore.push(snapshot2.data());
            });
        });
    });
});
```

However, this is very inefficient, since you can see that you are performing 2 reads + 1 read per grade, if you are willing to change your data structure, it would be much simpler to have it like this:

```
Collection: Student
   Document
      id: Johny
      Subcollection: Grade
         Document 
           id: Math
           score: 10
         Document
           id: History
           score: 8
```

And then you could query it with:

```
var JohnyScore = []
db.collection("Student").where("id", "==", "Johny").get().then(function(doc) {
    doc.collection("Grade").get().then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(score) {
            JohnyScore.push(score.data());
        });
    });
});
```

Which would mean you only perform 2 reads.

Hope this helps.